# ¿Cómo hago para poner una etiqueta (<h4> y <p>) en una posición específica?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy haciendo una página — será una presentacion para mi equipo de trabajo — y quiero hacer que un `<p>` y un `<h4>` esté a la misma posición vertical que otro `<h4>` y `<p>` pero en una posición horizontal diferente.

La idea es transformar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los códigos:

CSS:

```
#title /* Esto es el titulo principal */ {
    font-size: 65px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
}

#sub-title /* Este es el subtitulo con "" */ {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
}

#parraf1 /* Esto es el "¿QUIENES SOMOS?" */ {
    font-size: 27.5px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#parraf2 /* Esto es el "¿QUE HACEMOS?" */ {
    font-size: 27.5px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#parraf1description /* Esta es la descripcion del "¿QUE HACEMOS?" */ {
    font-size: 23.5px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

#parraf2description /* Esta es la descripcion del "¿QUE HACEMOS?" */ {
    font-size: 22.5px;
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

¿Cómo hago para hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: hay falta gente... coloca tambien el html, para poder ayudarte..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes solo usar un contenedor [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), de manera que puedes acomodar un contenedor al lado del otro.

> CSS Grid layout contiene funciones de diseño dirigidas a los desarrolladores de aplicaciones web. El CSS grid se puede utilizar para lograr muchos diseños diferentes. También se destaca por permitir dividir una página en áreas o regiones principales, por definir la relación en términos de tamaño, posición y capas entre partes de un control construido a partir de primitivas HTML.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.grid-container > div {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* 
  Usa un media query para hacer que el grid sea adaptable a dispositivos móviles 
*/

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <!-- Aquí va el contenido -->
    <h3>¿Quienes somos?</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Aquí va el contenido -->
    <h3>¿Qué hacemos?</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Aquí va el contenido -->
    <h3>Fila 2</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Aquí va el contenido -->
    <h3>Fila 2</h3>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona!

Comment: Pero ¿Si quiero hacer lo mismo abajo? Osea si añado uno a la derecha, uno a la izquierda, y luego quiero hacer lo mismo abajo, como hago?

Comment: @Skeletoos57 Solamente añade más etiquetas `<div>` al grid, o añade otro contenedor.

Comment: Podrias editar tu respuesta para hacer lo que te digo si no es molestia? Es q lo intente y no funciono

Comment: @Skeletoos57 He actualizado mi respuesta, comprueba si es lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias, ahora si :D